# Spring Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace, Offending resource: class path

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-batch, quartz-scheduler

I am stuck at an issue which I am unable to resolve. I have spring batch application powered with Quartz scheduler and Gradle. Everything is working fine locally. But when I'm building the jar using Gradle and trying to run it below exceptions are thrown.

```
Jun 09, 2020 5:14:01 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@15551852: startup date [Tue Jun 09 17:14:01 IST 2020]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 09, 2020 5:14:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:118)
```

I tried to place the xsd file locally, but still getting this error. Below is my application.context file.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    spring-context-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool
    spring-tool.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    spring-batch-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.*.*" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="traJnsactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

    <batch:job id="compareVersion">
      <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet ref = "versionComparisonTasklet" />
      </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
```

I am using gradle to build the jar file and copying all the dependencies within the Jar. Below is my build.gradle file.

```
group "org.*.*"
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
        'Implementation-Version': version
    }
    baseName = 'BatchJob'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.4.0'
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '4.3.12.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '4.3.12.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '4.3.12.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '4.3.12.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '4.3.12.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.batch', name: 'spring-batch-core', version: '3.0.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-oxm', version: '4.3.12.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.9.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.9.1'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.12.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.validator', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.3.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-c3p0', version: '5.2.12.Final'
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.4'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '4.3.12.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.2'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.9.2'
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-spring4', version: '3.0.9.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf', version: '3.0.9.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'aopalliance', name: 'aopalliance', version: '1.0'
    compile group: 'cglib', name: 'cglib', version: '2.2'
    compile group: 'asm', name: 'asm', version: '3.1'
    compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.2.11'
    compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-core', version: '2.2.11'
    compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'
    compile group: 'com.sun.xml.wss', name: 'xws-security', version: '3.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.ws.security', name: 'wss4j', version: '1.6.19'
    compile group: 'com.thoughtworks.xstream', name: 'xstream', version: '1.3.1'
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9.9'

    xjc 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.1.12'
    xjc 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.1.12'
    xjc 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.2'
}



buildDistributionZip {

    into('dist/config/dpw/cdi-org-structure-ws-v1/wsdl') {
        from ("${projectDir}/misc/resources/schemas/cdi-org-structure-ws-v1/wsdl") {
        }
    }
}

test { systemProperties 'property': 'value' }

uploadArchives {
    repositories { flatDir { dirs 'repos'
        } }
}

task copyToJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
        'Implementation-Version': version
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-dependencies'
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    with jar
}



jar {
manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
        'Implementation-Version': version,
        'Main-Class': 'org..MyJobScheduler'
  }
    baseName = 'batchjob'

  from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}


task runBatchJob(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner'
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    args = ["applicationContext.xml", "versionComparisonTasklet"]
}
```

My Main Class

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException {  
    JobDetail j=JobBuilder.newJob(MyJobBuilder.class).build();  
    Trigger t=TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("CroneTrigger").withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInHours(72).repeatForever()).build();    
    Scheduler s=StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
    s.start();
    s.scheduleJob(j,t);

    }
```

I am just not sure, what changes I am supposed to make to run the executable jar. I am running the jar using bat file with -jar command. Please help me guys, unable to make any progress, I am just stuck.

Comment: Use something like https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/ to create a fatjar which is executable. Or even better use Spring Boot for better compatibility. When using a fatjar you also need to add classpath entries to the Manifest else those won't be loaded.

Comment: Spring boot is not possible since effort will be more. All I wish to run this jar. I am able to run it locally but not the jar. never worked on fatjar, can you please let me know how to implement it, we are using gradle 4.10

Comment: I pointed you to a gradle plugin that does that for you.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum for this, I am still getting the same error

Comment: INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]

Comment: @M.Deinum any idea on how to resolve above issue

Comment: #1 Could you  share us a hello world (github) with the same issue ? #2 Is Maven an option?

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk Please can you confirm that when you run the main inside the ide or gradle task, you haven't the issue, but when you run built with the task ```task copyToJar(type: Jar)``` and run the command ```jar -jar your_jar.jar``` then the exception occur ? Thanks

Comment: is spring-context inside your fatjar?

Comment: You are likely overwriting files with the same path but from different libraries, such as `/META-INF/spring.handlers`. To fix it, and you like to package your application as a fat jar, you need a proper tool to construct it in a way that avoids overwriting files with the same path. Spring Boot and Shadow (like already mentioned) are the most popular ones. Otherwise, you should think about packaging the application in a different way, such as using the Gradle Application and Distribution plugins.

Comment: I solved the issue by appending spring handler to manifest file. Thanks everyone for your help... I will update my question with updated solution.

Answer (score 2):

As posted, your URLs are wrong. They are missing a `/`. The correct header should be:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
```

Your configuration above was missing the `/` between `context` and `spring-context-4.3.xsd`.

Answer (score -1):

I bumped on this article. Hope this make some sense for you.

https://robert-reiz.com/2011/11/14/832/

It says you should have `transformer` configuration

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
  <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
</transformer>
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
  <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
</transformer>
```

Comment: Please stop guessing. They're not even using Maven's shade plugin for creating uber jars.

Comment: And provide evidence in your answers. `AppendingTransformer` will merge the contents of any duplicate resources that have the given name. But none of their dependencies do. So this wouldn't do anything anyway.